# Teams members can't log in to chat.SE with private browsing

Tags: bug, chat, login

Since a short while back, I cannot seem to log in to the SE-hosted chat from my phone any longer.

I am active in [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) and so I frequently get pinged from that chat room while I'm off-line ... but I cannot log in on my phone to reply. I can log in to Stack Overflow just fine, but when I click the inbox notification, it doesn't recognize me (that's a separate bug which has been [reported before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252214/links-between-my-se-accounts-should-bypass-login), though fixing this would certainly alleviate this problem too) and when I try to log in to `chat.stackexchange.com` it says "Team members must log in to Stack Overflow directly."

I can repro this on the desktop site, too, by opening a browser in anonymous mode.  This is what I see *after* I have ostensibly successfully logged in to `chat.stackexchange.com`:

[image: "Team members must log in to Stack Exchange directly."]

Maybe my mobile browser is not so good at carrying over some credentials. I have Safari on IOS perpetually running in anonymous mode because weird apps sometimes suddenly open something in the browser.

Comment: Are you saying the log in on SO fails? I can repro the redirect to SO login which makes me login again, but everything works as expected once I do

Comment: Safari doesn't allow third-party cookies, which is what breaks the flow here. Other browsers (e.g. Chrome) should log you into stackexchange.com as well when you log in on stackoverflow.com and thus grant chat access.

Comment: I experienced this on my phone as well (LastPass browser). This only affected chat.stackexchange.com - I'm not sure of my browsers third-party cookie policy, so it may have been the same situation mentioned by Adam. What worked for me was logging in to a site on the SE network under the *.stackexchange.com domain, for example, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/